# How to loop through a list of dictionaries in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, loops, dictionary, flask

I have an SQL request that gives me all the data I need (in Python)
I made it so that I have a list of dictionaries, it looks like that:

```
data = [{
    "jour_de_la_semaine": "0",
    "nom_rue": "Avenue Rogier",
    "total_lourd": 4464.676489954501,
    "total_pieton": 366.75719346780005,
    "total_velo": 1530.4361518144,
    "total_voiture": 16283.220910553997
}, {
    "jour_de_la_semaine": "1",
    "nom_rue": "Avenue Rogier",
    "total_lourd": 4689.496674622601,
    "total_pieton": 719.5071498280998,
    "total_velo": 6835.787324285102,
    "total_voiture": 22114.002369259702
}, 
..., 
...]
```

I put the variable in the return template so that I can use it on JavaScript.
I'm using this to do the list in JavaScript:

```
var data = '{{ all_data_rue|tojson }}';
```

I can easily see all the data with a simple `console.log(data);` but its impossible for me to loop through it... It always return me characters per characters.

I've tried every single solutions I could find on the Net. I've also find a post where it has the exact same problem but the solution didn't work...

I'd like to get dictionaries per dictionaries and not characters per characters.
Any solution?

Comment: You have JSON. Parse it to get a JS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var data = '{{ all_data_rue|tojson }}';
```

Try:

```
let data = JSON.parse('{{ all_data_rue|tojson }}');
```

or even just:

```
let data = {{ all_data_rue|tojson }};
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer !

Your first solution work perfectly ! Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
var data = '{{ all_data_rue|tojson }}';
```

You are setting `data` to a string representation of `all_data_rue`. If you want to access the information from Javascript, you can do

```
var data = {{ all_data_rue|tojson|safe }};
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer !

Its good to know ! 
I've tried your solution but it didn't work.. Hopefully, Miguel G solution's work well !

Comment: @Loup How did this option not work? Did you get an error or something?

Comment: I think the '{{ all_data_rue|tojson }}' set data to a string representation as you said.
The problem is that when im not using ' ', it gives me 3 error:
- Property assignment expected.
- ',' expected.
- Declaration or statement expected.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong...